# How does a micro-controller process instruction from its code segment in the memory?

Tags: microcontroller, processing

I have been working with an Atmega 328 PU for a while and I understand how the .hex file is transferred into the chips code segment in memory . I have looked at the architecture of the Atmega 328 and it raises questions in my mind as to how are instructions processed in the processor , or in other words , how does the binary instruction ex : 1000001 get processed by the micro-controller. I searched the web but found nothing helpful. Can anybody give a good answer on how a instruction is processed by the micro-controller's processor ?

Comment: This is a very broad question, basically you are asking how a CPU works. There are books devoted to just that topic...

Answer (score 1):

Within the CPU each binary instruction performs a logic, arithmetic, storage, or flow operation. These sequential operations accomplish the tasks described by the program. You can search “machine code”, “logic synthesis”, and “sequential logic” for more information.

Comment: The answer is incomplete ? It didn't mentioned that how which part of CPU executes the instrcution and how the cpu executes the instruction ?